# PHP array traversing with ordered key suffixes

Tags: php, json

I have to parse this JSON in PHP so that for each address, I get the address, line and city information and store it in the database. The way that I plan to implement is like this:

```
For each key in the json string, check if it begins with address,
If yes, split the string based on '_' and get the index count. 
Get line1, line2, city for this index count.
```

Is there a better way to do this?

(Note that the index count can be random)

```
{
  "route": "A",

  "address_0": "A0",
  "line1_0": "L1_0",
  "line2_0": "L2_0",
  "city_0": "city_0",

  "address_1": "A1",
  "line1_1": "L1_1",
  "line2_1": "L2_1",
  "city_1": "city_1",

  "address_2": "A2",
  "line1_2": "L1_2",
  "line2_2": "L2_2",
  "city_2": "city_2",

}
```

Comment: a way such as PHP's built-in [JSON extension](http://php.net/json_decode)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just iterate over the data and assign to an array:

```
$route = array();
foreach(json_decode($json) as $p => $v)
{
   list($k, $i) = explode('_', $p, 2) + array(NULL, NULL);
   if (NULL === $i) {
       $rc =& $route["$k $v"];
       continue;
   }
   $rc[$i][$k] = $v;
}
unset($rc);
```

gives:

```
array(1) {
  ["route A"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["address"]=>
      string(2) "A0"
      ["line1"]=>
      string(4) "L1_0"
      ["line2"]=>
      string(4) "L2_0"
      ["city"]=>
      string(6) "city_0"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(4) {
      ["address"]=>
      string(2) "A1"
      ["line1"]=>
      string(4) "L1_1"
      ["line2"]=>
      string(4) "L2_1"
      ["city"]=>
      string(6) "city_1"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(4) {
      ["address"]=>
      string(2) "A2"
      ["line1"]=>
      string(4) "L1_2"
      ["line2"]=>
      string(4) "L2_2"
      ["city"]=>
      string(6) "city_2"
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3lB24u)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use this format instead

```
{
  "route": "A",
  data : [{
      "address": "A0",
      "line1": "L1_0",
      "line2": "L2_0",
      "city": "city_0"
  },{
      "address": "A1",
      "line1": "L1_1",
      "line2": "L2_1",
      "city": "city_1"
  },{
      "address": "A2",
      "line1": "L1_2",
      "line2": "L2_2",
      "city": "city_2"
  }]
}
```

and get it like this

```
$json = '    {
      "route": "A",
      data : [{
          "address": "A0",
          "line1": "L1_0",
          "line2": "L2_0",
          "city": "city_0"
      },{
          "address": "A1",
          "line1": "L1_1",
          "line2": "L2_1",
          "city": "city_1"
      },{
          "address": "A2",
          "line1": "L1_2",
          "line2": "L2_2",
          "city": "city_2"
      }]
    }';
$object = json_decode($json);
echo $object->data[0]->address; // A0
echo $object->data[1]->address; // A1
//and so on...
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the incoming JSON, I need to handle it as-is.

Comment: Exactly what I was getting at, but much more thorough.

Comment: @user330973: Wow. So contact owner of the api and tell them that they have to change it. Because this really, really sucks

Comment: It really does suck. If the owner is willing to change it, that would be the easiest for you.

Comment: So a little background about where I get the JSON from. Its from a form which contains fields (address) that is inserted dynamically into the form. The form ids and values are then converted into JSON that is processed by my PHP file.

Comment: @user330973: so you'll have use your first "worse" way

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one because even the JSON isn't formed very well (address_0 vs address_1) instead of something like

```
{
    "route" :
        { "address" : "something", "line1": "something else" },
        { ... }
}
```

I would do a `json_decode` to turn what you have into an array, then parse the keys appropriately and pass the values into a DB object (or loop and save).

Comment: I think the plan you have to deal with the poor JSON is the best approach.

Comment: I was looking for a solution where I might not need to loop through the JSON twice, but looks like that how I might end up doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
$json = {
  "route": "A",

  "address_0": "A0",
  "line1_0": "L1_0",
  "line2_0": "L2_0",
  "city_0": "city_0",

  "address_1": "A1",
  "line1_1": "L1_1",
  "line2_1": "L2_1",
  "city_1": "city_1",

  "address_2": "A2",
  "line1_2": "L1_2",
  "line2_2": "L2_2",
  "city_2": "city_2",

}

$object = json_decode($json);

$route = array();
$currentRoute = "";
$addressCounter = 0;

foreach($object as $key => $value)
{
    if($key == "route"){
        $currentRoute = $value;
    } else {
        $explode = explode("_",$key);
        $route[$currentRoute][$addressCounter][$explode[0]] = $value;
        if($explode[0] == "city"){
            $addressCounter++;
        }
    }
}

print_r($route) 

// Should return something like
// Array (
//    ['A'] => Array (
//                [0] => Array (
//                        ['address'] => 'A0',
//                        ['line1'] => 'L1_0'
// ...
```

It's nasty, but it works. Again...if you have control over the original form, I would just rethink that approach to better be handled here.

Good luck!